# Besides skewness and kurtosis, how else can I investigate changes on a distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, skewness, kurtosis

I want to look for changes on the distribution of the laying date of a bird (i.e. if the phenology or nesting synchrony has changed). Are the coefficient of variation, skewness, kurtosis the only way to detect these changes? I was not able to detect any change with these analyses. The temporal trend of the mean does not show change either. But when looking at the data it seems that there are some changes.

When I set the first value (first nest) of every year to 1 I get this: [image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks from your plot like you're trying to detect changes in the mean, or perhaps a quantile (like the median). Why would kurtosis be relevant?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b! kurtosis is relevant because we cannot find changes directly on the mean or median but maybe there are small changes on the shape the distribution (skewness or kurtosis). I already tried mean and median but I did not find anything. Looking at the data I can see that in early years they used to nest later, but I cannot detect it with the analysis. Can I use quantile regression to see effect of year on the distribution? Thanks!

Comment: based on this link, I guess the answer is yes: http://wise.xmu.edu.cn/UploadFiles/SS2011/Uploadfiles/2013714144421348.pdf